# There cannot be more than one relational path between any two tables in the graph

Tags: database, filemaker

I'm building a database in Filemaker and I have a problem linking tables. Basically, I have a table "capture" showing an event where a photo will be taken. Someone will be dealing with "capture" meaning that there will be a responsible for "capture" to be recorded properly. The photo taken in "capture" will be recorded in a second table "photos". Another person could be responsible for the photo management. So I have a "Observers" table which will be my contact table. I want to be able to link the "Observers" table with the "capture" AND the "Photos" table so that the names in "Observers" populates both tables.

But if I do the link like in the image below:

[image]

I get this error:
"There cannot be more than one relational path between any two tables in the graph."

[image]

How can I like the 2 tables, if possible? I know it makes an "ambiguous" path, but there might be a way to reutilize the information in "Observers" to inform 2 different tables that are linked together.

I want to do something like this:

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use another occurrence of the Observers table.
See: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/adding-tables.html

Recommended reading:
http://www.nightwingenterprises.com/Resources/approaches_to_graph_modeling_en.pdf

Comment: Wouldn't that be duplicating all the data?

Comment: No. It merely places another representation of the same table on the graph. This allows you to refer unambiguously to the correct observer. Otherwise, from the context of Photos, you wouldn't be able to tell if `Observers::last_name` means the person responsible for the capture or the person responsible for the photo.

Answer (score 0):

-- Edit
Let's bring back to basics because when trying to define a model, the concept must have been well defined before.

Am i understand it well :
One or more observer are being assigned to work on a capture (evenement, place...).
The observer(s) take one or more Photo about the capture place.
And so one or more photo of a place can have been taken.

If that's true, we have the following relation

[image: Conceptual Data Model]

Here we are !
So what about the Logic Model of the database.

We can say that we have the following table :

CAPTURE(id_capture)
--> With id_capture being Primary Key of CAPTURE
OBSERVER(id_observer)
--> With id_observer being PK of OBSERVER
CAPTURE_OBSERVER(id_capture, id_observer)
--> With id_capture being FK of CAPTURE, and id_observer being FK of OBSERVER
PHOTO(id_photo, id_capture, id_observer)
--> With id_photo being PK of PHOTO, id_capture foreign key of CAPTURE, id_observer foreign key of OBSERVER

I hope i'm right, if not please correct me about the purpose of every entity in this model.

I think by adding this new table that i found (CAPTURE_OBSERVER) you'll be able to solve your problem AND to improve your model conception.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a picture showing what you are saying. Is it the solution you are referring to? Is this common practice to do?

Comment: Hello, yes this is a verry common practice. When you have a many to many relation you always have to create a table to do the link.
Please watch this nice video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pv7P9R9JI-E

Comment: The many-to-many relationship between Observers and Photos is already resolved by the Capture join table. I see no reason why you would need another one.

Comment: Actually @M.Beausoleil want to do the link between Observer and Photos for being able to access the name of observer directly from Photos. And he want to access this name from Capture too. So as i understand, he want to have a relation between all the three tables. That's why he come and ask the question, because he don't like the way it was done before.

Comment: But also because the double link doesn't work in filemaker...